# Two divs on top of each other for team page

Tags: html, css

I realize this is probably another newbie question but I have tried different things and can't make this work. I am basically building a team page where I want to have a picture on the left side and some text on the right side for each team member. Under the name of the person comes the title, and below that (between title and a paragraph) is a bunch of badge links for email, LinkedIn, and Twitter. For the purpose of having the badges align perfectly below the title, I have used a table. I want to repeat that set up for each team member and have them stack on top of each other.
What I have right now for one person (which displays correctly) in html:

```
<div class="left">
    <img src="url"/>
</div>
<div class="right">  
    <H3>Name</H3>
<H4>Title</H4>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="mailto:email"><img src="url"/></td>
    <td><a href="http://linkedin.com/url"><img src="url"/></a></td>
    <td><a href="url"><img src="url"/></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>Experience</p>
<p>Experience</p>
<p>Experience</p>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.left img{
      position:relative; 
      float:left;
      height:15%;
      width:15%;
      top:50px;      
}

.right{
       position: relative;
       float:left;
       margin-top:10px;
}

.right h3{
    color:#39c388;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:28px;
    position:relative;
    top:30px;
    left:20px;
}

.right h4{
    color:#818286;
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:24px;
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
}

.right td img{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
}

.right td{
    width:30px;
}

.right p{
    color:#818286;
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    position:relative;
    top:40px;
    left:20px;
}
```

So far so good. Now, I want to replicate this code and have these section stack up on top of each other. How would you do that? I have tried having a div around this whole html code and then give that div a class, and used position, z-index, etc but without any success.

Comment: provide a fiddle please

Comment: Sorry, what's a fiddle?

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean 'stack on top of each other' as in layered over each other, then you need to use:

`{position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0}` (having top and left position to the position you require)

on the container `<div>`s for each section.

However, if you mean 'stack on top of each other' as in listed down the page, then it should work with a container `<div>` as is. You may need to give the container `<div>` and the `left div` an `{overflow: hidden}` (and `{height: 1%}` for IE 6 - 8) to count for the floating child elements within them.

Comment: Thank you! It does in a way fix the issue. What I have now are two divs (for two team members) with all the code I wrote up there. I also added per your guidance the overflow:hidden. That changed the layout from having the two sections aligned horizontally to vertically (which is what I want). It however does cut some of the text between the <p></p>. Any idea why and how to fix it?
I really appreciate your help!

Comment: That's probably because you are using the 'top' attribute. Instead of 'top', use 'margin-top'. Reserve the 'top' attribute for absolute and fixed position elements.
(This goes for the 'left' attribute as well, use 'margin-left' instead).

Also, it may help if you setup a fiddle (fiddle.jshell.net) with your code in it, and even a small mockup of how you want the page to look.

I've also noticed a small HTML error in your code, there is no ending </a> tag in here:

<td><a href="mailto:email"><img src="url"/></td>

Comment: Thank you! That did take care of it. It's strange to me why the overflow:hidden command makes the second div go below the first vs. just next to it. Thanks also for spotting the missing </a>!